# How can I improve the performance while inserting to a list in while looping C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, c#-4.0

How can I improve the performance of below code block. The distinctUniqueIDs list is having more than 10000 records. I have tried parallel execution ,but its not yielding much difference. Is there any other space for optimization

```
for (int i = 0; i < distinctUniqueIDs.Count; i++)
{
    long distinctUniqueID = distinctUniqueIDs[i];
    try
    {
        if (!SmartAppConfigMapDict.ContainsKey(distinctUniqueID))
        {
            appconfigTemp = new SmartAppconfigRootElementMap();
            filteredList = validAppConfig.Where(m => m.UniqueID == distinctUniqueID);

            if (filteredList?.Count() > 0)
            {
                appconfigTemp.AppConfig = filteredList.First();
                appconfigTemp.RootElements = filteredList.ToDictionary(m => 
                    m.RootElementVersionID, m => m.RootElementName);
                appconfigTemp.RootElementPrimaryKeyMaps = filteredList.ToDictionary(m => 
                    m.RootElementVersionID, m => new RootElementPrimaryKeyMap
                {
                    RootElementName = m.RootElementName,
                    RootElementVersionID = m.RootElementVersionID,
                    ChildElementDesc = m.ChildElementDesc,
                    ChildElementName = m.ChildElementName,
                    ChildElementPath = m.ChildElementPath,
                    ActualRootElementVersionID = m.ActualRootElementVersionID,
                    ActualRootElementName = m.ActualRootElementName
                });

                SmartAppConfigMapDict.Add(distinctUniqueID, appconfigTemp);

                if (queryRootElementMap.ContainsKey(appconfigTemp.AppConfig.QueryID))
                {
                    queryRootElementMap[appconfigTemp.AppConfig.QueryID]
                        .Add(appconfigTemp);
                }
                else
                {
                    appConfigRootMapSubList = new List<SmartAppconfigRootElementMap>();
                    appConfigRootMapSubList.Add(appconfigTemp);
                    queryRootElementMap.Add(appconfigTemp.AppConfig.QueryID, 
                        appConfigRootMapSubList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: No amount of parallel execution will help to significantly speed up code that uses wrong data structure... Most likely one of your "contains" checks is not using dictionary lookup. `.Where` call looks more suspect at a first glance.

Comment: filteredList?.Count() - Can you not loop over and if no record exists then skip.

Comment: validAppConfig - What Type of collection is that? Array/List - can you optimize that?

Comment: filteredList.ToDictionary() - is done twice - can you try reduce that? All our suggestions will be generic. You have the advantage of knowing implementation, so you are best placed.

Comment: if *filteredList` is of type `IEnumerable` then its better to use `filteredList?.Any() ) vs *Count*

Comment: At a first glance, I noted a small thing:
I suggest changing from filteredList?.Count() > 0 to filteredList?.Any()
This has little impact on performance, but it is recommendable.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Its a list type.How can I optimize two dictionary convertions?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What is the 'wrong' data structure you are mentioning about? Is there any suggestions

Comment: @Kailas - Do the appconfigTemp.RootElementPrimaryKeyMaps Dictionary Conversion, and then use it to create appconfigTemp.RootElements. Note that the Key is same for both Dictionaries, you just have to extract Value.RootElementVersionID.

Comment: The blanket `try/catch` may cause some perf issues if a lot of exceptions are being thrown. Can you not replace that with proper validation and error handling?

Comment: @Kailas, can you confirm if one of the answers below solved your problem, or if you need more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit should be

```
filteredList = validAppConfig.Where(m => m.UniqueID == distinctUniqueID);
```

First, LINQ `Where` is inefficient method with linear time complexity O(N). Using such methods inside loops is not recommended.

Second, due to LINQ deferred execution, the aforementioned linear search is executed several times - basically by every operator applied to `filteredList` - `filteredList?.Count()`, `filteredList.First()` and 2 `filteredList.ToDictionary(…)` calls.

What you can do is to prepare in advance a fast hash based lookup data structure (for instance, [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8)) outside the loop and use it inside.

e.g. add something like this outside the loop:

```
var validAppConfigsByUniqueID = validAppConfig.ToLookup(m => m.UniqueID);
```

and the inside replace

```
filteredList = validAppConfig.Where(m => m.UniqueID == distinctUniqueID);

if (filteredList?.Count() > 0)
```

with

```
var filteredList = validAppConfigsByUniqueID[distinctUniqueID];

if (filteredList.Any())
```

Note that `validAppConfigsByUniqueID[distinctUniqueID]` operation has constant time complexity O(1). And returned enumerable is already buffered, so iterating it several times is not an issue.